# Mudar cor de fundo de forma dinâmica

Tags: react, styled-components

Eu tenho esse código que pega as informações de um Pokémon e eu queria mudar a cor do background de Type dependendo do tipo do Pokémon. Caso ele seja elétrico ficar amarelo, de água ficar azul etc. Como eu faria isso?

````
<Info>
              <strong> {data.name}</strong>
              <strong > Type: {pokemonType}</strong>
             <strong> Height: {data.height}</strong>
          <strong> Weight: {data.weight} kg</strong>
     </Info>
  ```
````

Answer (score -2):

Faça uma função pra retornar a cor de acordo com o tipo, e determine o background-color de maneira dinâmica, pode fazer usando o useRef ou assim :

```
function getTypeColor(type){
  switch(type){
    case 'earth': return 'brown';break;
    case 'water': return 'blue';break;
    case 'electric': return 'yellow';break;
    // repetir todos os tipos retornando suas cores, usar rbg ou hex pra cor exata
    default: return 'black'
  }
}

<Info>
   <strong> {data.name}</strong>
   <strong style={{backgroundColor:getTypeColor(pokemonType)}}> Type: {pokemonType}</strong>
   <strong> Height: {data.height}</strong>
   <strong> Weight: {data.weight} kg</strong>
</Info>
```

Se quiser apenas o tipo com cor diferente, basta envolver apenas o tipo numa div com a lógica acima, assim:

```
<strong> 
  Type: <strong style={{backgroundColor:getTypeColor(pokemonType)}}>{pokemonType}</strong>
</strong>
```

Answer (score -3):

Você poderia criar uma função com object literals. Exemplo:

```
function getBackgroundColorType(type) {
const colorsType = {
    earth: 'brown',
    water: 'blue',
    fire: 'red',
    electric: 'yellow',
    // E assim por diante...
};


const lowerCaseType = type.toLowerCase();


if (colorsType.hasOwnProperty(lowerCaseType)) {
    return colorsType[lowerCaseType];
}

// Caso o tipo não seja encontrado, retorne uma cor padrão
return 'gray'; // ou qualquer outra cor que você queira usar como padrão
```

}

```
 <div style={{ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColorType(type) }}>
  <h1>{name}</h1>
  <p>Type: {type}</p>
</div>
```